# Google map with multiple waypoints repeatative

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I tried something which is a bit out of norm on google map.  What I am trying to achieve is to draw a route with multiple waypoints which are sometimes can be repeative.  Let says, an Origin: A and Destination: B, and waypoints {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 2, 1}
From above, it will always failed.  If I take out the repeat locations it will display the route.
Please help.  Thanks in advanced.

```
wayPoints.push(
    {location:new google.maps.LatLng(stepsWP[0], stepsWP[1]),
    stopover: false
        }
...
var request = {
            origin: start,
            destination: end,
            waypoints: wayPoints,
            optimizeWaypoints: false,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };

    var directionsRen = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);
    directionsRen.setMap(map);
    directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {

        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsRen.setDirections(result);
        }else{
            console.debug('Something wrong with google...');
        }
    });
```

Comment: As a hack, could you take repeating waypoints and make them unique by adding a VERY small distance in either direction to one of them?

Comment: No not really, bcoz eventually if I have 2 route which is using the same waypoint then it becomes a problem.

Comment: I think I got the answer, looking at the error response, MAX_WAYPOINTS_EXCEEDED, check this link http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2361  anyone have any good ideas to workaround this?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.
I did some google and found some of the suggestions on the workaround.
http://techquarries.blogspot.com/2010/08/using-more-than-8-waypoints-in-google.html
http://lemonharpy.wordpress.com/2011/12/15/working-around-8-waypoint-limit-in-google-maps-directions-api/
http://mostup.com/2011/02/15/google-map-api-v3-directionsservice-more-than-8-waypoints-workaround/

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I got from Google Map Direction service page:

> The maximum allowed waypoints is 8, plus the origin, and destination.
>   Google Maps API for Work customers are allowed 23 waypoints, plus the
>   origin, and destination. Waypoints are not supported for transit
>   directions.

So you basically need to break down your waypoints array into groups of 8 locations and use that to send requests to google direction service api.